# My python multiprocessing program runs the worker programs sequentially

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have written a python program using multiprocessing. The program invokes a 8 worker which outputs a random number after sleeping 3 second.  I expect the program finishes in 3 seconds but it finishes in 24 seconds, as if each worker function is evaluated sequentially rather than in parallel. Any idea?

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import sys

def f(i):
    np.random.seed(int(time.time()+i))

    time.sleep(3)
    res=np.random.rand()
    print "From i = ",i, "       res = ",res


if __name__=='__main__':
    num_workers=mp.cpu_count()     # My CPu has 8 cores. 
    pool=mp.Pool(num_workers)  
    for i in range(num_workers):
        p=pool.apply_async(f, args=(i,))
        p.get()

    pool.close()        
    pool.join()
```

However, if I use Process instead of Pool, I get the right results as expected:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import sys

def f(i):
    np.random.seed(int(time.time()+i))

    time.sleep(3)
    res=np.random.rand()
    print "From i = ",i, "       res = ",res
    if res>0.7:
        print "find it"


if __name__=='__main__':
    num_workers=mp.cpu_count()
    pool=mp.Pool(num_workers)
    for i in range(num_workers):
        p=mp.Process(target=f,args=(i,))
        p.start()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think about what you're doing here:

```
for i in range(num_workers):
    p=pool.apply_async(f, args=(i,))
    p.get()
```

Each time through the loop, you send some work off to a pool process, and then (via `.get()`) you *explicitly wait* for that process to return its result.  So of course nothing much happens in parallel.

The usual way to do this is more like:

```
workers = [pool.apply_async(f, args=(i,)) for i in range(num_workers)]
for w in workers:
    w.get()
```

That is, you start as many workers going as you want *before* you wait for any of them.

Comment: You could also use `pool.map(f, range(num_workers))`, which does the gathering of the results for you.

Comment: @Blckknght, sure - I assume the OP's question is a vast simplification of what they really want to do, and that `apply_async()` makes better sense than `map()` in their real application.  But, of course, I don't know that ;-)

Comment: Coming here 4 years later, your comment saved my day! @TimPeters

Comment: Thanks for this, was wondering why my processes were sequential/linear as well, and this cleared things up!