# Why does python multiprocessing run sequentially?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I try to speeds up the dot product of two large matrice, so I test a small example of multiprocessing. The codes are as follows. But from the results, I found that my codes runs like sequentially.

**Codes**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time


def dot(i):
    print(f"Process {i} enters")
    np.random.seed(10)
    a = np.random.normal(0, 1, (5000, 5000))
    b = np.random.normal(0, 1, (5000, 5000))
    print(f"Process {i} starts calculating")
    res = np.dot(a, b)
    print(f"Process {i} finishes")
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    dot(1)
    print(time.perf_counter() - start)
    print('=============================')
    
    print(mp.cpu_count())
    i = 8
    start = time.perf_counter()
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    res = []
    for j in range(i):
        res.append(pool.apply_async(dot,  args=(j,)))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    end = time.perf_counter()
    # res = [r.get() for r in res]
    # print(res)
    print(end - start)
```

**Results**

```
Process 1 enters
Process 1 starts calculating
Process 1 finishes
2.582571708
=============================
8
Process 0 enters
Process 1 enters
Process 2 enters
Process 3 enters
Process 4 enters
Process 5 enters
Process 6 enters
Process 7 enters
Process 4 starts calculating
Process 7 starts calculating
Process 5 starts calculating
Process 3 starts calculating
Process 1 starts calculating
Process 6 starts calculating
Process 0 starts calculating
Process 2 starts calculating
Process 4 finishes
Process 7 finishes
Process 1 finishes
Process 0 finishes
Process 6 finishes
Process 2 finishes
Process 5 finishes
Process 3 finishes
27.05124225
```

The results showed that the codes seems to run indeed parallelly (from the text), but the final running time seems run sequentially. I don't know why, so hope some one could give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My python multiprocessing program runs the worker programs sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961987/my-python-multiprocessing-program-runs-the-worker-programs-sequentially)

Comment: I don't think so.   The problem in the question you refer to is that of running the thread such that a later thread had to wait for an earlier thread to finish before it could start  (i.e. the same behaviour if you used apply rather than apply_async)  Here even when running the threads asynchronously  you get a run time as if you ran the thread synchronously.  I go the same results on my machine which has four cores.  Replacing the dot product with a call to sleep did produce a speed increase,

Comment: @William Thanks William, but I am running the processes rather than the threads. I think the processes do not need to wait the previous processes to finish, it can run parallely, but the results do not show that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is always additional overhead involved in creating processes and in passing arguments and results between address spaces (and in this case your results are extremely large).

My best guess is that the performance problem is arising because the storage requirements for running 8 processes in parallel (I assume you have at least 8 logical processors, preferably 8 physical processors) due to the large arrays being computed is probably causing extreme paging (I get the same results as you). I have therefore modified the demo to be less memory intensive but kept the CPU requirements high by performing the `dot` function many times in a loop. I have also reduced the number of processes to 4, which is the number of *physical* processors that I have on my desktop, which gives each process a better chance of running in parallel:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import numpy as np
import time


def dot(i):
    print(f"Process {i} enters")
    np.random.seed(10)
    a = np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 50))
    b = np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 50))
    print(f"Process {i} starts calculating")
    for _ in range(500_000):
        res = np.dot(a, b)
    print(f"Process {i} finishes")
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.perf_counter()
    dot(1)
    print(time.perf_counter() - start)
    print('=============================')

    i = 4
    start = time.perf_counter()
    pool = Pool(i)
    res = []
    for j in range(i):
        res.append(pool.apply_async(dot,  args=(j,)))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    end = time.perf_counter()
    # res = [r.get() for r in res]
    # print(res)
    print(end - start)
```

Results:

```None
Process 1 enters
Process 1 starts calculating
Process 1 finishes
6.0469717
=============================
Process 0 enters
Process 0 starts calculating
Process 1 enters
Process 1 starts calculating
Process 2 enters
Process 3 enters
Process 2 starts calculating
Process 3 starts calculating
Process 0 finishes
Process 1 finishes
Process 3 finishes
Process 2 finishes
8.8419177
```

This is much closer to what you would expect. When I change `i` to 8, the number of logical processors, then the running times were 6.1023760000000005 and 12.749368100000002 respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My laptop is M1 mbp, so I guess I have 8 pysical processors. From your answer, can I think that the problem of my demo is due to the memory allocation and the overhead costs. But I have another problem. Do you think the demo code has somewhere blocks the multiple processes to run paralelly? Because I saw on the forum, someone said that the numpy will change the CPU affinity and for large matrix calculation, numpy will use the openblas or Cblas to make the codes run sequentially.

Comment: I don't know `numpy` internals well-enough to answer that. You might be able to find out elsewhere. It is clear, however, with my demo that it is probably using 4 processors (or at least 3, but I say 4 because I do not expect to see the running time the same because of the aforementioned multiprocessing overhead). **It is certainly *not* running sequentially,**